# Library JSch, Sudo script does not work for Centos

Tags: java, linux, ssh, sudo, jsch

I'm using the JSсh library. I need to shutdown the computers Linux OS (Ubuntu, Fedorо, Centos). There are no problems with Ubuntu and Fedoro. But with Centos problems.
I can shutdown only under the user "root". But if I use the user "john" with the rights of the superuser, the script hangs on entering the password and nothing happens. I will be very grateful for any help.
Below I present the code

```
public class Sudo {
private static final int timeout = 10000;
public static String sudo_pass = "john123";

public static void main(String[] arg) {
        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            String user = "john";
            String host = "192.168.56.103";
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
            UserInfo ui = new MyUserInfo();
            session.setUserInfo(ui);
            session.connect(timeout);

            String command = "sudo poweroff";

            ChannelExec channel = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

            // man sudo
            //   -S  The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the
            //       standard input instead of the terminal device.
            //   -p  The -p (prompt) option allows you to override the default
            //       password prompt and use a custom one.

            channel.setCommand("sudo -S -p '' " + command);
            channel.setPty(true);

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();

            channel.setErrStream(System.err);

            channel.connect();

            out.write((sudo_pass + "\n").getBytes());
            out.flush();

            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
            while (true) {
                while (in.available() > 0) {
                    int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                    if (i < 0) break;
                    System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                }
                if (channel.isClosed()) {
                    System.out.println("exit-status: " + channel.getExitStatus());
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ee) {
                }
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKV7G.png)

Comment: *"script hangs on entering the password"* - Where does it hang **exactly**?

Comment: Why do you call `sudo` twice?

Comment: I'm quite sure that the script is hanging on the line 
`channel.setPty(true);`
When I call `sudo` once the console writes an unknown command. If I call `sudo` twice this problem is not present. I will repeat this code perfectly works on Ubuntu and Fedoro.
Sample on the website of the library [link](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sudo.java.html)

Comment: `setPty` only assigns an internal field. No way that could hang. + *"When I call sudo once the console writes an unknown command"* - Show us a screenshot both with one and two `sudo`s.

Comment: You are really right. Calling two `sudo` was useless. Everything works great.
Today the Centos began to turn off sometimes. I can't understand what's the matter. The script enters the password for the `sudo commands` and the console hangs. I attach a screenshot in post.

Comment: There is no problem if I disable the password request for shutdown for the user john in sudoers file. But it does not fit.

Comment: Though that's the correct approach. Setup a special account for the shutdown. And allow it to do `sudo shutdown` without a password.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. But this is not an option. There are too many servers. Root user also doesn't fit. It is necessary to register the actions of each user.